# CQWP-Opening Excel Links through XLViewer

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

Just wanted to get some help with this CQWP issue.
So I have a CQWP that pulls Excel and other files from multiple document libraries based on a filter. The document libraries are set to open files in browser.  How do I get it so that the link will render in the XLViewer rather than trying to save and open in Excel?